# Filtering a View with row_number for generating serial number

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, filtering

I have a view like this.

```
Create view RefStatus
as
select row_number() over(order by Inserted_On desc) Slno, Name,
Email_ID Email, Mobile_No Mobile, Status, Inserted_On ProfileCreatedOn from RefTable
```

Now

```
select  Slno, Name,
 Email,  Mobile, Status,  ProfileCreatedOn from RefStatus
```

is fine, I get serial numbers as expected. But when I try

```
select  Slno, Name,
 Email,  Mobile, Status,  ProfileCreatedOn from RefStatus where Status = 'In-Progress'
```

my serial numbers doesn't get generated properly. It still considers all the records of my table as base and generates serial numbers which is not correct.
How do I generate serial numbers for filtered rows alone.

I know that this can be done through stored procedures or by creating separate views for each status. Is there a way to do it in the same view? The reason is that I need to call this view from C#, using entity framework and linq.

Comment: Don't you have a PK in `RefTable` table?

Comment: Nope, actually I don't have any RefTable, I mentioned it for simplicity, my actually select query is a big one with multiple inner joins and left joins on around 15 tables

Comment: If you're going to use this serial number in order to identify a row, then this won't help, as the `Inserted_On` column data may change this mean the `SerialNo` also will change.

Comment: No, I will not update anything with that key, I actually wanted the `SlNo` to change with filtered data, but it isn't happening. `SlNo` remains same with filtered and unfiltered data for the rows.

Comment: Alright then @Prasanth Kumar Vinakota you already has the answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` that is generated in the view is not dynamic, in the sense that it does not dynamically changes when you filter the view.

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` in the query rather than in the view:

```
select  
    row_number() over(order by Inserted_On desc) SlNo, 
    Name,
    Email,  
    Mobile, 
    Status,  
    ProfileCreatedOn,
from RefStatus
where Status = 'In-Progress'
```

Comment: Ultimately I need to call this view from C# using entity framework linq. Is it possible to do that in C#.

Comment: @PrasanthKumarVinakota: yes you can run this query from c# of course.

Comment: Right now I am calling it like this `grvNewRefGrid.DataSource = db.RefStatus.Where(g => g.Status == str).ToList();` How do I generate serial number here, also one more reason why I am generating serial number in view is that entity framework needs a key to work properly, I am using this column as key.